# Call a method from a Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have a method inside a Fragment that I need to call from the activity.

The activity runs fine If I add this code into the Activity, but I want to keep my activity clean and keep the code in the fragment.

**How do I do this?**

This is the method from the Fragment

```
public void Foreg(final View v) {
    ValueAnimator box = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0, 1);
    box.setDuration(1500);
    box.start();

    box.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            float value = ((Float) (animation.getAnimatedValue()))
                    .floatValue();
            v.setRotationX(value * -180);
            v.setPivotX(v.getWidth() / 2);
            v.setPivotY(v.getHeight());
            v.setCameraDistance(10000);
            v.setClickable(false);

            /*
             * float value = ((Float) (animation.getAnimatedValue()))
             * .floatValue(); v.setRotationY(value * -160); v.setPivotX(00);
             * v.setPivotY(300); v.setCameraDistance(3500);
             * v.setClickable(false);
             */

        }
    });

    ValueAnimator box2 = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(1, 0);
    box2.setDuration(1500);
    box2.setStartDelay(4000);
    box2.start();

    box2.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            float value = ((Float) (animation.getAnimatedValue()))
                    .floatValue();
            v.setRotationX(value * -180);
            v.setPivotX(v.getWidth() / 2);
            v.setPivotY(v.getHeight());
            v.setCameraDistance(10000);
            v.setClickable(true);

            /*
             * float value = ((Float) (animation.getAnimatedValue()))
             * .floatValue(); v.setRotationY(value * -160); v.setPivotX(00);
             * v.setPivotY(300); v.setCameraDistance(3500);
             * v.setClickable(true);
             */
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question, you want to call fragment method `Foreg(View v)` from activity.

Try this way:

```
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();    
YourFragmentClass fragment = (YourFragmentClass)fm.findFragmentById(R.id.your_fragment_id);
fragment.Foreg(View v);
```

Comment: Just a question, where do I get "R.id.your_fragment_id"
Thanks!

Comment: In your layout xml file. If you are not added fragment via xml, then you have to get your fragment by tag for example.
Here is a example:
YourFragmentClass fragment = (YourFragmentClass)fm.findFragmentByTag("yourTag");

Comment: I created a ViewPager with Fragments, how do I get the Id or Tag?